# creating JavaFX popup window with html layout

Tags: java, javafx

I want create javafx popup window which will load some html into it. But as I see javafx PopupWindow can not have custom scene with layout
Actually I want to show some popup near window bottom or top angle which will look like antivirus alert, like this

[image]

The window should not change focus on itself, it should be transparent.

Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe this is what you are looking for:

http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#notifications